# how to change the color of a button using onclick on other button using javascript or ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

i want to change the color of a button say on a page `g.php` by clicking on a button present on `s.php`. `g.php` has been included into the `s.php`. So, is it possible. I will be very thankful to you if you answer it.

Comment: so us the code for g.php and s.php

Answer (score 1):

To change colour of button in javascript function use the code below:

```
document.getElementById("button").style.background='#000000';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
$("#button1id").click(function(){
   $("#button2id").css("color","red");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the both buttons rendered in same page, add them some identificators like `<button id="btn1" /> <button id="btn2"/>` and than use for example jQuery framework and write this code `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#btn1").on("click",function(){ $("#btn2").css("background-color","yourcolor")});
});`

edit : sorry I had an error in my code I have changed }) to )}, anyway here is working exapmle

http://jsfiddle.net/t5YRT/

Comment: well and do you have jQuery script file included to your page?

Comment: ye i have done like this,   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">

$(document).ready(function(){ $("#btn1").on("click",function(){ $("#btn2").css("background-color","yourcolor")}); )};

</script>